# Is Virtual Sadhana the same as in person?

Tags: sadhana

Recently I have seen news making headlines of the Sadhana App for ios and Android devices for Hindus to be able to practice Sadhana in a modern way thats environmentally friendlier and also much more simpler for Hindus to connect with traditional elders who wish to practice in a traditional way, but I am confused about whether this has any benefit or if it should even be trusted as a legitimate way of worship to the Devata. Is this a legit way to perform Sadhana? I have seen other worship apps coming out as well and even downloaded one and it has a virtual altar like one I have at home where you can virtually do arti and other rituals. Are these legit?

Comment: Firstly, an app for doing Sadhana is absolutely nonsense. There are some things like respiration & reproduction which need to be done physically, & sadhana is one of those things. Secondly, if you think that doing Sadhana is equivalent to doing Arati & Puja only, then you are living in a very big delusion.

Comment: See, though it's not totally legit but it has it's own benifits. Like it helps people to remain connected n true to their roots. Especially, the busy ones, younger generations and older people. Human mind is fickle so it helps to one extant. Something is better than nothing. Right..

Comment: I think this is supposed to aid you in strengthening the mental worship part of sadhana, which is far superior to physical one.About the efficacy, its up to you to decide.If you have unshakable faith in the Guru who made this app, and unconditionally surrender to him, God will have no choice but to listen to you, if not for a sincere seeker who then does God manifest for?

Comment: @অনু If doing sadhana on a app seems nonsense, taking inspiration and doing the same rituals physically can be alternative too! Because the one who made the app is someone who has actually practised those sadhanas multiple times and invoked the devata's living energy for the world to benefit.Even if it seems unconventional and i believe it deserves a shot! (Disclaimer even i don't use the app and do physical sadhanas. But i trust the Guru who made it completely.)